# How can I set an instance variable with a date_select form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an archive page that I want the user to be able to select a date  and pull up microposts created on that date.  I think I am close to figuring it out, I just cannot figure out how to set an instance variable with a date_select form.  I have a method in my controller that looks something  like this:

```
def archive
  @date_search = []
end
```

I want to set the instance variable to an empty set for now so that it can be assigned later. My partial for the feed looks like this:

```
<ol class="microposts">     
<%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection:Micropost.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", @date_search) %>
</ol>
```

I can assign @date_search a value in the controller and it will show posts from that date so that seems to work. Now I just need to be able to set the variable with the form.  My date form looks something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@date_search) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">       
    <%= f.select_date Date.today, :prefix => :date_search %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-lrg btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

but I doesn't work.  Maybe I am using the wrong kind of select date form because if I don't put the f in front of select_date in the block the forms show up in the view but nothing happens when I submit it.  When I put f.select_date I get this error

`undefined method 'select_date' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x0000010170f3d0>`

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used form_tag in the view and the datepicker gem in a text field tag to create a live update in a form.

e.g.

```
<%= form_tag the_controller_path, method: :get do %>

<%= submit_tag("date update") %>

<%= label_tag(:q, "Selected Date") %>

<%= text_field_tag :q, @date_search, :class => 'datepicker' %>
```

That gets the user input.

@date_search here is what will displayed in the text box when the date is updated.

You then use params[:q] in the method to use the selected date in the controller.

e.g. in the controller:

```
def archive

    @date_search = params[:q]

end
```

Maybe something like this would work for you?

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_date) `select_date` does not appear in `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder`, so I would try it without `f`. Also, they use it with a date object:

```
my_date = Time.now + 6.days

# Generates a date select that defaults to the date in my_date (six days after today).
select_date(my_date)
```

I am not sure about this though.

Or maybe you want [date_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select).